# How can I control CSS transitions and animations with JS?

Tags: javascript, css

I have an image that goes from opacity 0 to 1 when a bit of text is hovered. I would like the transition to be smooth, something similar to CSS transition. Can't really figure out how to make this happen, so any help would be appreciated.

The JavaScript looks like this:

```
    document.getElementById("text-hover").addEventListener("mouseover", imageTransition);
document.getElementById("text-hover").addEventListener("mouseout", imageTransitionOut);
function imageTransition() {
    document.getElementById("pic").style.opacity = "1";
}
function imageTransitionOut() {
  document.getElementById("pic").style.opacity = "0";
}
```

Comment: *something similar to css transition.* --> why not using transition then? you will complicate your life trying to do such simple thing with JS

Comment: because it needs to be a child or sibling, right?

Answer (score 2):

Just define the transition in css, it will trigger when you change the opacity value in javascript:

```
#pic {
  transition: opacity .3s;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

You don't need to change your javascript

### Update

If you need to animate more than one property, it is better to define the animation in css and then trigger it from javascript by toggling a class on the element
the css:

```
#pic {
  transition: all .3s;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(.1);
}

#pic.animate {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

javascript:

```
var textHover = document.getElementById("text-hover");
var pic = document.getElementById("pic");

textHover.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    pic.classList.add('animate');
});

textHover.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    pic.classList.remove('animate');
});
```

Comment: I'd recommend adding a class to the element with the pic id and adding the transition property to the class instead of the id.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This works fine. Besides the opacity transition, i would like the image to scale down. How would i go about? Cant seem to figure out in which class to put the transformation scale

Comment: @Jeppe look at the updated answer for how to animate more than one css property